# Angular 2 with TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0, typescript1.5

I am a Angular 2 newbie. I am familiar with TypeScript and Angular 1.x.

**Question 1:**
I am looking for free learning resources that can teach me Angular 2 with TypeScript for beginners. Please give me some ideas about good online resources to learn. I searched some online resources but they are confusing to me.  Thank you.

**Question 2:**
If I work with Angular 2, does it has a separate syntax/approrach for TypeScript or Angular 2 already includes TypeScript in it ?

I already know for Angular 1, if I follow native Angular, then it is not a strongly typed. But I am following TypeScript, then Angular 1.x coding is more strongly typed with interfaces, classes. So, definitely, for Angular 1.x, The coding pure-Angular-native approach is different from the TypeScript approach   Thank you.

Comment: 1) Have you read the documentation? 2) Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1:** They are literally tons of resources available online to learn Angular 2 and Typescript, I would personally recommend you to read the [Tour Of Heroes tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) on the official Angular 2 Website or [Getting Started with Angular 2 by Deborah Kurata](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-getting-started-update/table-of-contents) which is a pretty decent resource to learn and start with Angular 2.

**Answer 2:** Angular 2 is designed to work with Typescript, the whole documentation is even written with Typescript, you'll never be stuck it will perfectly work with it. You are safe about that point.

Comment: Hi Sakuto, Thanks so much for your help. I will take a look at those links.